# Sagepay non-english support

Tags: globalization, opayo

We currently have a Server intergration with the sagepay API, when the time comes for the card details to be entered the user is redirected to the sage pay website which displays all the information in english. Does anyone know if its possible to specify which language sage pay uses to display information on its site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be available when the next protocol version is available as far as I know.

Regards.